# update database on login in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, authentication

I have a `user` column in database which have `viewed_at` column with type `date`.

[image: viewed_at]

I want to update that field on every user login.

I wish to run the code on every user login --

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
$user->viewed_at = /* current date */;
$user->save();
```

Please help me with this issue.

**Please don't suggest me to do it in controller to which the authenticated person is redirected to.**

Comment: Maybe something simple like `$user->viewed_at = 'NOW()';`

Comment: you should do it in your Auth controller. What's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 5.3 you can override `authenticated()` method in `Auth\LoginController.php` and put the logic there. Also since Laravel always gets an instance of an authenticated user, you could save one query by using `auth()->user()` object.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

....

protected function authenticated()
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    $user->viewed_at = Carbon::now();
    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: using `authenticated()` method in `Auth\LoginController.php` disturb the default login function?

Comment: @Advaith no. `login()` calls `sendLoginResponse()` which then calls `authenticated()`

Comment: As far as you'll always be authenitcating through default `\Auth\LoginController` methods this should be a sufficient solution.

Answer (score 4):

The `Auth` class provides [a handful of useful events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#events). One of them is `Login`.

[Listen to this event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events#defining-listeners) and update the `$user->viewed_at` when it's triggered.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
$user->viewed_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```